# Is there a function to decompose a TypeScript/Angular class into attributes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, class

is there a way to remove the outer class and get all attributes and inner classes of it? As an example: I have a Angular service who receives a "Branch" class:

```
    createBranch(branch: Branch): Observable<Branch> {

    const token: string = sessionStorage.getItem('a-ut');
    const apiUrl = environment.apiHostLumen + '/branch?token=' + token;

    const body = { branch };
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(apiUrl, body, options).pipe(
                    retry(1),
                    map(res => res.json()),
                    map(data => {
                      if (data.success) {
                        return BranchFactory.fromJson(data.result);
                      }
                    }),
                    catchError(this.ehs.handleError('createBranch'))
    );
  }
```

But the API needs in the request body the single attributes inside the branch class (without the outer branch). It's awkward to send every single attribute / inner class like `branch.name`, `branch.age`,... Is there a way to abbreviate that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try spreading your branch into the body :

```
const body = { ...branch };
```

This will "explode" your branch and get rid of the structure.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's often the little things that help so much.